# Using Apache CXF wsdl2js tool for stub generation has issues in order of elements

Tags: node.js

I have one WSDL file and using Apache CXF - wsdl2js tool to generate stub file in node js. But the order of the elements ,changed. Comparing with WSDL and STUB the order is changed. can anyone help me on this to rectify the issue.

Tried with new version of Apache CXF, but issue remains same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.